# Is there need to convert coordinate from world to viewport in OpenGL after defining viewport?

Tags: opengl

When we define viewport and world coordinate, does OpenGL automatically convert the given point to be put in viewport or do we have to explicitly convert them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL applies modelview and projection transformations to coordinates and, after that, applies a transformation that maps rectangle [-1, 1]x[-1, 1] to the viewport.

To achieve one-to-one correspondence between world coordinates and the viewport, you should probably set a proper modelview/proection transformation ([glOrtho](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) could help here).

A precise article on what is going on [OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)

Comment: Does that mean when I am using GL_PROJECTION mode, glViewport() and gluOrtho2D then it will map the point correctly on Viewport without explicitly mapping on to viewport.

Comment: @sarsjits yes, it should work. Don't forget to return to GL_MODELVIEW matrix mode if you are going to use some other transformations.